# how do I bring a vm created with testdrive under kvm or qemu?

Tags: 11.10, kvm-virtualization, qemu, testdrive

After installing oneiric with testdrive, how do I bring it under aqemu or kvm?

Answer (score 1):

On my system testrive puts the image files in `~/.cache/testdrive/images`. You can just use normal kvm to launch any of those images, for example:

```
kvm -m 2048 -hda ~/.cache/testdrive/images/testdrive-disk-SauBO5.img
```

Launches the image with 2 gigs of RAM.

- [KVM manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/kvm.1.html)